# repostioning column or copying column

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have imported a table from excel and called tblData, I already have table in access that is called tblAcc and I have to move the records from tblData to tblAcc. The problem is the fields are not on the same order.

ex:
tblData:

```
PARTNAME NUMBER COST
JK15     251    55
```

and in tblAcc:

```
PARTNAME COST NUMBER
CH61      14     6
```

So how can I transfer from table to table column by column OR how can I rearrange columns in tblData?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to move the data from one table to the other would be to build what Access calls an `Append` query.

Using the query builder, you can line up the fields so that they map properly, and load the data that way.

SQL something like this should work, too:

```
INSERT INTO tblAcc (PARTNAME, COST, NUMBER)
SELECT PARTNAME, COST, NUMBER 
  FROM tblData;
```